# How force DbContexts to read from the connection string in the right appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have multiple DbContexts in my project
I am using .Net 6 and efCore 6. I am passing connection string to the contexts like this.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{    
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public MyContext() : base() { }
}
```

And in program.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("MyConnrctionStr").Value);     
});
```

The problem is I should delegate the creation of my DbContext to a third party library that does not pass connection string to the context.
So I should handle setting the right connection string in my dbContext classes themselves. Also the config should come from corresponding environment settings i.e. development, production, debug, ...
So that should be something like this:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{    
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public MyContext() : base() { }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        var string connectionStr= //Read ConnectionString From Correct appsettings.json file Regarding to Environment
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionStr);
        }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this 3rd party library publicly available? Maybe it supports DI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have current environment name in the class and then read the appsetting.[currentenvironment].json with some code like this.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(getConnectionString());
    }
    private static string getConnectionString()
    {
        var environmentName =
          Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
              "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings" + (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environmentName) ? "" : "." + environmentName) + ".json", false).Build();
        return config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
```

This way you do not need to send any thing when injecting DBContext, etc. But the name of connection string would be hard codded inside DbContext

Comment: @N-Hassan note that configuration is using hierarchical approach to the sources in .NET and possibly you will want to repeat the whole setup for sources, not just one file (cause for production environment usually it is just `appsettings.json`, for example, or the setting can come from environment variables or key vault)

Comment: @N-Hassan also potentially creating a config builder per context instance creation is not a very good idea due to performance implications.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks guru. I fully understanded you second comment about the performance, but not the first one. Can you elaborate? Or give me a link to read more because I am using this setup in multiple projects and I should improve it due to your valuable comments.

Comment: @N-Hassan yes, sure - please read [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and/or [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration). Point being that your connection string setting can potentially come from multiple sources i.e. for production environment it can come from `appsettings.json` not `appsettings.Production.json` or even from environment variable.

Comment: Not to count the fact that it could already be configured using the other constructor. So the code at least should be `if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) { /** do something default **/ }`. Also reading from app settings file (which file? in which folder?) when called from another "app" is doubtful.